# How to Update the Following Table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have the following data set as displayed below (Oracle 11). The end goal is to update the `INC` column to 1 for **only** one record in every grouping based on `COLX` and `COL3` column while all the other records in this subgroup of `COLX` and `COL3` should get 0 based on the following rules:

For every distinct value in `COL3` and `COLX`, e.g. *M1* and *1*, I need to set only a single record to 1 (among all three, K1, K2 and K0) based on the earliest date in `COL2`, and if they are the same date, get the row based on the order of `COL1`, e.g. *K1*, *K2*, or *K0* in this case.

However, there is another rule I need to consider before this, and that is, if the value of `COL4` is smaller than a certain value, e.g. *16*, then the record should get `INC=1` (note that I am not saying if `COL4` should have the lowest value, but rather, whether it satisfies `COL4 < 16` condition). In case of `COL3=M`, the first two records have values of *10* and *12*, so they should be considered as opposed to *K0* that has `COL4=17`.

Putting this all together, in case of records with `COL3=M1` and `COLX=1` value, *K2* should get 1, while the remaining subset, *K1* and *K0*, should get 0.

Or in case of `COL3=D1` and `COLX=1`, *K0* should get `INC=1` while the other two, *K1* and *K2*, should get `INC=0` since `COL4 < 16` for all of them, and *K2* and *K0* has the earliest `COL2` date, but *K0* gets `INC=1` because when ordering *K2* and *K0*, *K0* comes on top.

```
+-------------+--------+---------------+------------+--------+--------+
| COLX        | COL1   | COL2          | COL3       |COL4    |INC     |
+-------------+--------+---------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 1           | K1     | 2019-04-03    | M1         |10      |0       |
| 1           | K2     | 2019-01-10    | M1         |12      |1       |
| 1           | K0     | 2019-04-10    | M1         |17      |0       |
| 1           | K1     | 2019-05-13    | D1         |12      |0       |
| 1           | K2     | 2019-04-22    | D1         |8       |0       |
| 1           | K0     | 2019-04-22    | D1         |15      |1       |
| 1           | K1     | 2019-04-13    | C1         |30      |1       |
| 1           | K2     | 2019-04-13    | C1         |30      |0       |
| 1           | K0     | 2019-04-22    | C1         |44      |0       |
+-------------+--------+---------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Keep that in mind that this is an `UPDATE` operation. I have tried partitioning with lead and lag but can't get it working.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SQL you've tried. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have some way to uniquely identify a given row in each group, then you can identify the row by using `order by` and a subquery.  If `inc` starts out as `0` for all rows, then you can set the value to `1`.

Assuming that the unique rows are `(date, col4)`, then the query looks like this:

```
update t
    set inc = 1
    where (date, col4) = (select date, col4
                          from t t2
                          where t2.colx = t.colx and t2.col3 = t.col3
                          order by (case when col4 < 16 then 1 else 2 end),
                                   date asc, col4
                          fetch first 1 row only
                         );
```

You can adjust the columns for whatever is appropriate.

Oracle 11g supports the `fetch first` clause.  This is handy.  The query is a bit trickier in older versions of Oracle.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot assume a combination of `COL2` and `COL4` would be unique. The only unique combination in the table are `COL1` and `COL1`, OR, `COL1` and `COL3`. As a matter of fact, `COL4`'s for a unique `COL1` and `COL3` can have an identical value. I update the sample table with more data.

Comment: @NuCradle . . . You can use whatever columns you like for the comparison.  They simply need to uniquely identify each row.

Comment: I had no idea that you can do `CASE` inside `ORDER BY`. Your solution is very concise and to the point. Appreciate it. Just a side for the future readers: you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COL3 ORDER BY <Gordon's case logic and other order columns>)` to get "ranking". In this case, I was only interested in the first record on top.